# Idiom for “putting your cards on the table”

Tags: idioms

I am looking for a good idiom for the idea of being openly transparent with someone and being clear and straightforward, as in the English expression “putting all your cards on the table.” I found “metti le carte in tavola,” but I am looking for something more idiomatic and less of a literal translation.

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Comment: The expression is in my opinion idiomatic and largely used; an alternative could be _"dire pane al pane, vino al vino"_ , that means to call things with their real name, without embillishment or else.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi I think that "dire pane al pane e vino al vino" is closer in its meaning to the English "call a spade a spade", which is quite different from "putting all cards on the table"

Comment: @DenisNardin yes I think you are quite right; On afterthought, the most "Italian" version of _"putting your cards on the table_” should be (as on the answer of @abarisone) _giocare a carte scoperte_ that can have an origin with Italian card games like the "scopa".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible idiomatic expression can be **parlare [fuori dai denti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/D/dente.shtml)** that means to speak plainly, to put it bluntly, being clear, sincere, frank.

As correctly suggested by @RiccardoDeContardi is also idiomatic and largely used **[dire pane al pane, vino al vino](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pane1/)** which also means to call thing with their name, to speak plainly, frankly:

> **1c**. Locuzioni fig. e frasi proverbiali: *dire p. al p. (e vino al vino)*, chiamare le cose col loro nome, parlare in modo chiaro, con
>   franchezza;

Other possible expressions with the same meaning could also be:

- mettere le cose in chiaro
- dire le cose come stanno
- giocare a carte scoperte
- parlare con il cuore in mano

Comment: I would also add _"parlar franco"_ and _"parlar toscano"_ :)